# Setting Jackson 2 with Jersey and Tomcat

Tags: java, json, maven, tomcat, jackson

I have no maven project with Jersey and Tomcat. For my Json object for now i use lib:--> org.json.JSONObject. Now i want to integrate my project with Jackson but how?..
My web.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RESTful</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restJerseyServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>      
      <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json;com.rest.proof</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restJerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Example how i create a JsonObject:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    Element elementsByTag = doc.getElementsByTag("table").get(1);
    Elements rows = elementsByTag.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for (Element row : rows) {

        String ex = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(1).text();
        String exx = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(2).text();
        String exxx = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(3).text();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.put("Feat1", ex);
        jsonObject.put("Feat2", exx);
        jsonObject.put("Feat3", exxx);

        list.add(jsonObject);

    }
    json.accumulate("Response", 200);
    json.accumulate("List", list);

    String result = "" + json;
    return json;
```

i have this error when i try to consume a API:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Comment: If there is a full stack trace please post it.

Comment: now the problem is (i hope fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with this; in the web.xml i put:

```
 <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs;com.rest.proof</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

and use a ObjectNode not a JsonObject